# StackOverFlow while counting digits

Tags: clojure

I am trying to count the number of digits in a number in Clojure as follows: I get a StackOverflowError even for 2 digit numbers

```
(defn num-digits [n]
   (if (= 0 n)
   0
   (inc (num-digits (/ n 10)))))
(println (num-digits 93))
```

But if I replace / with unchecked-divide then it works for at least 93. But neither of the techniques works for:

```
93326215443944152681699238856266700490715968264381621468592963895217599993229915608941463976156518286253697920827223758251185210916864000000000000000000000000
```

First, I would like to know how to perform division the C-style in Clojure. Whenever I do (/ x y) I get a Ratio and not a Integer. What is the way to do it?

Secondly, is there a way API to convert this Number into a vector of digits and call count on it.

Thanks,
Ajay G

Comment: I dunno nothin' about Clojure, but shouldn't there be some way to convert the number into a string and then just get the string's length? Just about every other language I can think of has such a function.

Comment: log10: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27229987/can-i-know-how-many-digits-a-number-is-without-count-it

Answer (score 8):

This is why you're having a problem:

```
user> (take 10 (iterate #(/ % 10) 10923))

(10923 10923/10 10923/100 10923/1000 10923/10000 10923/100000 10923/1000000 10923/10000000 10923/100000000 10923/1000000000)
```

This is the fix:

```
user> (take 10 (iterate #(quot % 10) 10923))

(10923 1092 109 10 1 0 0 0 0 0)
```

This is the expression you're looking for:

```
user> (count (take-while #(not (zero? %)) (iterate #(quot % 10) 10923)))
5
```

This is cheating:

```
user> (count (str 10923))
5
```

This is the function you were trying to write (but careful, it will stack overflow for large numbers):

```
user> (defn num-digits [n]
        (if (= 0 n)
          0
          (inc (num-digits (quot n 10)))))

#'user/num-digits
user> (num-digits 10923)
5
```

However, it is up to the challenge:

```
user> (num-digits 93326215443944152681699238856266700490715968264381621468592963895217599993229915608941463976156518286253697920827223758251185210916864000000000000000000000000)

158
```

This version of that function will not blow stack:

```
user> (defn num-digits-tail-recursion 
        ([n count]
           (if (= 0 n)
             count
             (recur (quot n 10) (inc count))))
        ([n] (num-digits-tail-recursion n 0)))
#'user/num-digits-tail-recursion
user> (num-digits-tail-recursion 10923)
5
```

All versions are interesting in their own way. Good question!

Answer (score 4):

Clojure attempts to "do the right thing" with numeric operations and **never lose precision**. so when you device say 17/10 the result is the fraction 17/10 (seventeen tenths) not 1. By default no information will be lost in any of the numerical operations. In cases like this you can explicitly throw away the extra precision with `(quote x 10)` or you can cast the result to an int `(int (/ 17 10))`

for the second question here's a little hack:

```
(count (str 257))
```

A good way to keep from blowing the stack with recursion in Clojure is to use other higher order functions instead of recursion.

```
(count (take-while pos? (iterate #(quot % 10) 257))))
```

Answer (score 4):

There's no tail-call optimisation in Clojure. You have to use the [`recur`](http://clojure.org/special_forms#toc12) special form.

E.g.:

```
(defn num-digits [n]
  (loop [n n
         cnt 0]
    (if (= 0 n)
      cnt
      (recur (quot n 10) (inc cnt)))))
```

But in answer to your second question: yes, and this is how:

```
(defn num-digits [n] (count (str n)))
```

Comment: In the original code the call isn't even in tail position. So this code would fail in every other language just as well.

Answer (score 3):

According to [this page](http://java.ociweb.com/mark/programming/Clojure.html), you can perform integer division in Clojure using `quot`:

```
(quot n 10)
```