# Explanation of parameter value

Tags: clojure

This question is directly related to [StackOverFlow while counting digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2111891/stackoverflow-while-counting-digits) . I have lifted a solution from that question, and have a two questions:

First here is the solution:

```
(defn num-digits-tail-recursion 
        ([n count]
           (if (= 0 n)
             count
             (recur (quot n 10) (inc count))))
        ([n] (num-digits-tail-recursion n 0)))
```

1. count is a function in its own right for counting the number of characters in a string. Am I correct in assuming count is allowed as a var, because it's not in the first position of a list?
2. count is the second parameter, but I only am passing one parameter -- the number.
   What is special about the function syntax that starts with a list, rather than
   the typical parameter vector `(defn test_fn [x y] (println x))` ?

#### Edit:

I apologize for lack of clarity in the original question. Why does supplying a function name -- count -- not cause num-digits-tail-recursion to expect a second parameter? If I supply `([n x]...` instead of `(n count]...` and call the function with one argument, I get an insuf arguments error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question #1: Clojure is lexicaly scoped. so if you create a local var with the same name as a var defined in an enclosing scope the local copy will 'shadow' the outer one. In this case the `count` from clojure.core is the outer scope and the `count` from this function is covering it up. when you refer to `count` within this function you see the deffinition from the local functions argument list.

```
(def x 4)
(defn foo [x]
    (println x))
(foo 42)
=> 42
```

in your specific case `count` is defined in a different namespace, though the scoping concept is the same.

example of part 2:

```
(defn foo
  ([] (println "i have no args"))
  ([x] (println "i have one arg " x))
  ([x y] (println "i have two args " x " " y)))
```

Comment: Michiel's answer to part two coves this well. I will edit to add a code example. Check his answer for the link

Comment: So, do you think count was used to have a second parameter for recursion without having to supply it when the outer function was called?

Answer (score 2):

1. Naming args that carry functions the same as an existing function from a referenced namespace is not a good idea, although in your example here count is **not** used in that manner. In your example, count is just an int that gets incremented in every recursive iteration!

   But if you want to pass a count function and you name the argument which is used for it 'count', what function will be called? The function `clojure.core/count` or the passed function? (rectification: The passed function due to lexical scoping). So avoid confusion and choose a different name. Even if you're not passing functions it is still a good idea to avoid these names.
2. Functions support arity overloading and that is what you are using here now. Just read this: http://clojure.org/functional_programming

Comment: I'm a little confused as to changing the name count where and how count would be called.

Comment: @octopusgrabbus Michiel is saying that if you name a argument that takes a function "count", you will find that calling "count" will call the core function rather than your function. In your code "count" is just an int so this problem doesn't arise.

Comment: This is incorrect, though - if you bind a local named `count`, whether as a function argument or in a let-binding, and you then call that local as a function, `clojure.core/count` does not get involved at all - your function is called instead.

Comment: But I'm still confused. If I can supply a function (count) as the second parameter because function overloading is supported, then  how is count used inside the function, even if I use another var to keep track of the count?

Comment: In this case you don't need to pass a function to count, because the counting is done by *inc*-rementing the count **value** every iteration.