# Can I know how many digits a number is without count it?

Tags: clojure

When I want to know how many digits of a big number, I'd do this:

```
user> (count (str (factorial-bigint-loop 32)))
36
```

Is there a better way? Can I represent the number in scientific notation?

Comment: If your end goal is to output scientific notation, you can simply say `(format "%e" (bigdec n))`

Answer (score 2):

If the number is strictly positive, something like: `(+ 1 (floor (log10 n)))` should do the trick

Comment: can change floor+1 to ceil?

Comment: `inc` does the same as `+ 1`.

Comment: @edbond no, `(+ 1 (floor 1)) = 2` and `(ceil 1) = 1`

Comment: @mishadoff indeed, log10(10)=1.0 and 1.0.ceil=1 At least in ruby. Thx, sir!

Comment: The above yields a (floating point) *double*. Convert it to an (integer) *long*: `(defn digits [n] (-> n Math/log10 Math/floor long inc))`.